# How to disable QSB..?

Tags: android, searchbar

When a user presses the Search hard key on the device, Android shows the Quick Search Bar. How do I disable the Quick Search Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to completely disabled the Quick Search Bar, override the method `onSearchRequested()`and return true unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

override onKeyDown in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {            
        return true;
    } else return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. But I have found a better solution. I have overridden the method onSearchRequested() and returned true from there.