# Disable the search button in Android

Tags: android

I have a dialog in an Android app that I don't want the user to be able to cancel.  Using `.setCancelable(false)` disables the back button, but pressing the search button still cancels the dialog.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021739/disable-the-search-button-quick-search-box-in-android/7023495#comment12447188_7023495) which told me that I should include

```
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    return false;
}
```

But I'm still able to cancel the dialog with the search button.  Here's my code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        showDialog(0);
    }

    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        return false;
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Message")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // nothing
                   }
               });
         return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to have been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502443/prevent-progressdialog-from-being-dismissed-when-i-click-the-search-button-andr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Benh You need this code to set for your Key Listener for Dialog

```
   builder.setOnKeyListener(keylistener);
```

Add Below code in your Activity Class

```
  OnKeyListener keylistener=new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            return true; //we stop begin cancel of dialog or Progressbar
        }
        return false; 
    }
};
```

try this above thing in your dialog hope that will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.ACTION_DOWN==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
        return false;
    else
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I disable search button by overriding progress dialog. I create unnamed class and override method onSearchRequest() . And this is working for me.
I use this:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this){

                @Override
                public boolean onSearchRequested() {
                    return true;
                }           


            };
```

instead code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to listen for search button presses and do nothing when they are hit.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
            switch(keycode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                    return true;
                    break;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
        }
```

If this doesn't work for your `Activity` class then you'll probably need to create a subclass of `Dialog` and implement the `onKeyDown` method for your dialog class.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working for me.  I replaced the `onSearchRequested` function in my code with this code, except that I  removed the `break;` statement because Eclipse gave me an unreachable code error.  My dialog can still be dismissed by pressing the search button.

Comment: Hmm.. ok then you probably need to create a subclass of Dialog and override its `onKeyDown` method